# steps to install new android application onto new htc device

Tags: android

I need to install an android application running in my local machine on to my new android htc handset, how to do this,and i also need to give this application to someones htc device who is not near to me.

Comment: You need to give them the .apk file; additionally, in Settings, you need to allow 3rd party (non-market place) applications to be installed.

Comment: **[Signing your applications](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)**

Comment: Why? Apps don't need to be signed to be installed via `adb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your device, go to `Settings > Applications`. Tick `Unknown sources`. Go to `Development`. Tick `USB Debugging`.
2. Connect your device to your PC via USB cable.
3. If using Eclipse, when running your application you should get a dialog asking you which device to use where you'll be able to select your phone.
4. If not using Eclipse, build your app to an APK file (it mustn't be signed) and run `adb -d install /path/to/myApp.apk` in a terminal or command line

Send the `.apk` and these instructions to your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way to do this, without an USB cable. Upload your .apk to somewhere on the internet, and make your friend visit the link with his browser.

Ex. http://mydomain.com/apk/myappk.apk

He will automatically download the app and be promptet for install.

He needs to enable application from unknown sources. It does not need to be signed. (step1 from Felix)

Answer (score 1):

@Felix applications are indeed signed using a debug key during development.